# Django error with ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have started learning django and have a problem with INSERT-query using ORM (DB mysql).
My model:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    id         = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=True),
    schema_id  = models.IntegerField(),
    name       = models.CharField(max_length=50),
    desc       = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'keeper_record'
```

Following code is handle post query in view.py:

```
def add_record(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Record.objects.create(
            schema_id  = request.POST.get('schema_id', 1),
            name       = request.POST.get('name', 'd'),
            desc       = request.POST.get('desc', ' ')
        )

        record.save()

    return HttpResponse('')
```

But this code raising error:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/records/add/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'schema_id' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
Exception Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in __init__, line 364
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['D:\\Projects\\passkeeper',
 'D:\\\xcf\xf0\xee\xe3\xf0\xe0\xec\xec\xfb\\\xcf\xf0\xee\xe3\xf0\xe0\xec\xec\xe8\xf0\xee\xe2\xe0\xed\xe8\xe5\\PyCharm\\helpers',
 'D:\\Projects\\passkeeper',
 'D:\\Projects',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I install mysql driver for python and have standard settings for project, but only was removed csrf

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is these commas in your model definition.

You are setting `schema_id` to a tuple of a model field. `id = (models.AutoField(...),)`

Remove the trailing comma and you should be good to go.

```
class Record(models.Model):
    id         = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=True), # remove ,
    schema_id  = models.IntegerField(), # remove ,
    name       = models.CharField(max_length=50), # remove ,
    desc       = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'keeper_record'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really a rookie mistake:)

Answer (score 1):

The trailing commas in your model class definition are giving you problems, removing them should solve your problem.

A trailing comma (,) is creating a tuple with one element.

```
a = 1,
```

is equivalent to

```
a = (1, )
```

Which is a tuple of one element. What happends in your case is that your fields are not recognized by Django as model fields, since your fields are "wrapped" in a tuple.

See the Python documentation on tuples for more information:
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences